# Using 'nth' selectors in jQuery to target specific classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm still learning jQuery, and am unable to work out how to cleanly use 'nth' selectors to target the classes I want - even after looking at 'similar' threads, as I do not understand some of the code.

**My Goals:**

- That a specific 'Primary Filter' button will target a specific set of
  'Secondary Filters'.
- When a set of 'Secondary filters' are active and another 'Primary Filter' button is clicked, it will hide the previously displayed Secondary Filters.
- I'm also not sure why the transition isn't working but.. not important.

Please see my jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0azykcto/4/

For the website I am creating, there is potential that the person is going to add additional 'primary filter' buttons occasionally, along with a set of 'secondary filters' to go with them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(1)").click(function(){
    $('.secondary-filters:nth-child(2)').toggleClass("height");
  });
  $("#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
    $('.secondary-filters:nth-child(3)').toggleClass("height");
  });
  $("#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
    $('.secondary-filters:nth-child(4)').toggleClass("height");
  });
});
```

I was hoping there might be an easy way to loop this process perhaps. If anyone is able to point me in the rough direction of what I'm missing/how I might achieve this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/au149jth/ --  can add 1 more line of jQuery `$('.secondary-filters').not(':nth-child(2)').removeClass('height');`. and for the animation part, just replace `.height {height:22px !important;}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on indexes to make this easier and also use show/hide like below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

   var sel = "#primary-filters .btn";

  $(sel).click(function() {
    var i = $(sel).index(this);
    $('.secondary-filters').hide(); /*Hide all*/
    $('.secondary-filters').eq(i).show(); /*show the needed one*/
  });
});
```

```css
#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(1) {
  background: #dd6565;
}

#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(2) {
  background: #6587dd;
}

#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(3) {
  background: #65dd6e;
}

.secondary-filters {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
}

.secondary-filters:nth-child(2) .btn {
  background: red;
}

.secondary-filters:nth-child(3) .btn {
  background: blue;
}

.secondary-filters:nth-child(4) .btn {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-container">
  <div id="primary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Filter One</button>
    <button class="btn">Filter Two</button>
    <button class="btn">Filter Three</button>
  </div>

  <div class="secondary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
  </div>

  <div class="secondary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
  </div>

  <div class="secondary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or fade functions:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sel = "#primary-filters .btn";

  $(sel).click(function() {
    var i = $(sel).index(this);
    $('.secondary-filters').hide();
    $('.secondary-filters').eq(i).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```css
#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(1) {
  background: #dd6565;
}

#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(2) {
  background: #6587dd;
}

#primary-filters .btn:nth-child(3) {
  background: #65dd6e;
}

.secondary-filters {
  background: #F1F1F1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
}

.secondary-filters:nth-child(2) .btn {
  background: red;
}

.secondary-filters:nth-child(3) .btn {
  background: blue;
}

.secondary-filters:nth-child(4) .btn {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filter-container">
  <div id="primary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Filter One</button>
    <button class="btn">Filter Two</button>
    <button class="btn">Filter Three</button>
  </div>

  <div class="secondary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
  </div>

  <div class="secondary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
  </div>

  <div class="secondary-filters">
    <button class="btn">Button One</button>
    <button class="btn">Button Two</button>
  </div>
</div>
```